# React Native Facebook login Issue

Tags: react-native

i'm try to get userfriends list when login but it's not work i'm request public_profile, user_friends and only grant public_profile permission.

```
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
        'public_profile',
        'user_friends',
      ]);
      if (result.isCancelled) {
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Login success with permissions: ' +
            result.grantedPermissions.toString(),
        );
      }
```

and i'm getting response like this

```
Login success with permissions: email,public_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

**User Friends**

Represents a collection of Users who are friends of the app User. Only friends who have installed the app and who have granted the app the user_friends permission will be included.

**Limitations**

Only friends who have installed the app and who have granted the app the user_friends permission will be returned.

**JS Code**

```
FB.api(
  '/{user-id}/friends',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

**Response**

```
{
    "data": [], // A list of User nodes.
    "paging": {},
    "summary": {} //Aggregated information about the edge, such as counts. Specify the fields to fetch in the summary param (like summary=total_count).
}
```

**Error Codes**

```
Error   Description
100 Invalid parameter
200 Permissions error
368 The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed
190 Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token
459 The session is invalid because the user has been checkpointed
210 User not visible
```